# El ++ me suma de dos en dos

Tags: javascript, array

en este codigo no se porque en el for me va sumando de a dos en dos y no de uno en uno como debería hacer, alguien podría decirme donde esta el error?

```
let p = document.createElement("p");
let password = [];
let cantidad = prompt('Indique cuantos caracteres debe tener la clave');
generarPassword();

function generarPassword(){
    for(password.length = 0; password.length < cantidad; password.length ++){
        let caracter = container [Math.floor(Math.random()* container.length)] [Math.floor(Math.random()* container.length)];
        password.push(caracter);
    }
}
console.table(password);
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = password.join('');
```

Comment: ¿Porqué usas `password.length` como iterador? Eso no tiene sentido y es la causa de tu problema. Debes usar otra variable, por ejemplo la típica `i`: `for(let i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i) { ... }`. Saludos

Comment: Te suma de dos en dos porque el ciclo tiene `password.lengh ++ `  y dentro del ciclo de le haces un `.push()` por lo que una ejecución de ese bloque, realizas dos pasos que suman 1 elemento al password... Te sugiero usar algun debugger para ver como actua tu codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema ocurre porque estás usando length cómo iterador en el `for`, al final de cada ciclo incrementas en uno al utilizar `length++` pero dentro del ciclo `for` utilizas `push` que inserta un elemento a tu arreglo, entonces debido al `push` la longitud del arreglo aumenta en 1 y debido al `++` aumenta en 1, por eso en cada ciclo aumenta 2

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar otra variable como iterador

```
for(let i=0;i<longitudDeseada;i++)
```

Comment: La verdad que no sé porque estaba usando password.lenght ajajajaja pero muchas gracias por hacerme ver mi error, ya quedó solucionado!!!!